# XY coords for clicked point QGIS graphical modeller

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am trying to calculate a bearing from each point in a layer to a single target using the graphical modeller as its part of some other processing I need to do. I can do the bearing calculation (below) but is there a way to get X,Y coordinates from a mouse click and use that as the target?

(atan2((targetx-$x),(targety-$y)))*57.295779513082320876798154814105

Comment: I suggest you use the `azimuth` expression of the field calculator instead of your custom expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use "Point"-Input in your model:

[image]

It expects a user given point by clicking on the canvas and return `x,y [EPSG:xxxx]` e.g. `-0.12,12.4 [EPSG:4326]`. You can turn this into a geometry-point by using regular expressions like

```
make_point(
array_get(string_to_array((regexp_substr(to_string('-0.12,12.4 [EPSG:4326]'),'[^\\s]*'))),0),
array_get(string_to_array((regexp_substr(to_string('-0.12,12.4 [EPSG:4326]'),'[^\\s]*'))),1)
)
```

Where you should use `@point` as variable accessing this input instead of `-0.12,12.4 [EPSG:4326]`. Its your original input name without whitespaces and an @ in front. so your expression could be

```
(atan2((to_real(array_get(string_to_array((regexp_substr(to_string(@point),'[^\\s]*'))),0)-$x)),(to_real(array_get(string_to_array((regexp_substr(to_string(@point),'[^\\s]*'))),1)-$y))))*57.295779513082320876798154814105
```

Note, that you wont be able to test this when you run the model from the model builder. You need to save it first and run it from your processing toolbox, otherwise you wont get a chance to click on your canvas.

Comment: Cheers for the advice, I tried using the point input but I didn't get any option to click on screen when I ran the model and clicked the 3 dots so I assumed I was heading in the wrong direction, maybe it isn't running right or I have done something wrong elsewhere

Comment: @Sethinacan You can only click one point, not 3. If you need three points, you need 3 Point-Inputs. Also its a little annoying that you need to save your model first and run it from processing toolbox. If you run it from inside the model builder you wont be able to click on the canvas...

Comment: Not running it from the processing toolbox was the issue, and that might be the case for another model I have - many thanks

Comment: The Point Input is not available as Model Input in any algorithm I tried. Which algorithm would you use to create an actually usable geometry from it?

Comment: Nevermind, there is a Create Layer from Point algorithm exactly for this.